# How to add trailing space after some number of character (varchar) using sql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I need to display output data, I need to add/replace with white spaces with fix length for each column. Each column may got different length.

```
select  top (20)        
        patname + REPLICATE(' ', 30 - DATALENGTH(patname)) AS NAME,
        RefNo + REPLICATE(' ', 15 - DATALENGTH(RefNo)) AS REFNO,
        ClaimAmt AS AMOUNT    
    from  AR_Ebilling
```

Field length need to be set:

NAME = 30 varchar, REFNO = 15 varchar, AMOUNT = 10 money/decimal,

Expected Output Result :

```
NAME                           REFNO           AMOUNT
Ahmad Kasan                    1235            00000000565.93               
Amirah                         AY582M8D       -00023441200.23                   
Paul                           0ST127          00000004234.45
```

TQ

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that don't! One does not store redundant data in databases. All those white spaces are not really required to be stored because it's a trivial matter to pad out a string in your favourite programming language or even with in mysql itself. Towards this end mysql has :

[RPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad)

> Returns the string str, right-padded with the string padstr to a
>   length of len characters. If str is longer than len, the return value
>   is shortened to len characters.

And

[LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

> Returns the string str, left-padded with the string padstr to a length
>   of len characters. If str is longer than len, the return value is
>   shortened to len characters.

Also note that needlessly storing padded strings in the table makes it futile to use `VARCHAR`.

Comment: e4c5 actually i want to display data not storing the data

Comment: Good to know we are thinking of the same thing then. LPAD and RPAD are what you want